# Flutter Windows Desktop: Integrate with the File Activation API

Tags: c++, windows, flutter-plugin, flutter-desktop, flutter-platform-channel

I am looking for some guidance on implementing the Windows File Activation API with my Flutter App, that is, a user able to open a file associated with my App and have that file path passed to my app instance on startup and during runtime if the user opens a file whilst the app is already started.

I have found the following link from Microsoft that details how to achieve this within a UWP Application. However I have no been able to implement it completely with my limited knowledge of C++.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/handle-file-activation

1. It seems that the File Activation API relies on the WinRT API. Is this already bundled with the Flutter runner project or does this need to be imported separately?
2. To hook into the File Activation API, I need to create a class that is derived from the Application class, Is it possible to achieve this whilst still having a reference to the Platform Channels provided so that the events can be passed into the Dart code?
3. Is it even a valid approach to use the WinRT API's or is there another API I have missed?